# How to create simple menu in Python with list functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Please have a look at the exercise that i was asked to do. I am struggling for hours now to make it work.

There has to be a menu with the following choices: add a number, remove number (enter placeholder), show list.
Each time choice is made program should ask if we want to re-run the script.

Tried loops, functions and it just doesn't seem to work with me.

See the code below.

Thank you in advance!

```
def list():

    operation = input('''
Select operation:
[1] Add number to the list
[2] Remove number from the list
[3] Display list

''')
    mylist = []

    if operation == '1':
        print("Type the number you would like to add to the list: ")
        number = int(input())
        mylist.append(number)

    elif operation == '2':
        print("Type position of the element number you like to remove from the list: ")
        number = int(input())
        mylist.pop(number)

    elif operation == '3':
        print(mylist)

    else:
        print('You have not chosen a valid operator, please run the program again.')

    again()

def again():
    list_again = input('''
Would you like to see main menu again? (Y/N)
''')

    if list_again.upper() == 'Y':
        list()
    elif list_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('OK. Bye bye. :)')
    else:
        again()

list()
```

Comment: I would strongly disrecommend using `list` as a name for your function, since it is defined as a built-in type in Python. What about `input_number_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Verified Code**

```
mylist = []
def list():

    operation = input('''Select operation:\n [1] Add number to the list \n [2] Remove number from the list \n [3] Display list\n ''')


    if operation == '1':
        print("Type the number you would like to add to the list: ")
        number = int(input())
        mylist.append(number)

    elif operation == '2':
        print("Type position of the element number you like to remove from the list: ")
        number = int(input())
        mylist.pop(number)

    elif operation == '3':
        print(mylist)

    else:
        print('You have not chosen a valid operator, please run the program again.')

    again()

def again():
    list_again = input('''Would you like to see main menu again? (Y/N)''')

    if list_again.upper() == 'Y':
        list()
    elif list_again.upper() == 'N':
        print('OK. Bye bye. :)')
    else:
        again()

list()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Consider indenting the code that belongs to `list()`, this will not run as is.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting Consider the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/CITGuru/PyInquirer for than kind of menus.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have pointed out, your `mylist` variable needs to be moved. 
That said, I find that your mechanism of returning to the input query could be refined. See the code below. Here you keep everything in one function, without having to repeatedly ask the user if he/she would like to continue, it continues indefinately until you consciously `break` out of it.

```
def main():
    mylist = []
    while True:
        operation = input('''
Select operation:
[1] Add number to the list
[2] Remove number from the list
[3] Display list
[4] Exit programm

''')
        if operation == '1':
            print("Type the number you would like to add to the list: ")
            number = int(input())
            mylist.append(number)

        elif operation == '2':
            print("Type position of the element number you like to remove from the list: ")
            number = int(input())
            mylist.pop(number)

        elif operation == '3':
            print(mylist)

        elif operation == '4':
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid choice. Please try again.")

main()
```

Sidebar: "list" is a fixed expression in python. I would refrain from using it and others like it as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `mylist = []` outside of the function.